# Foundation Missing CSS in Essential package

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal, foundation-abide

on the download page it says that the package essential (foundation-6.3.0-essential) contains Reveal Modal and Abide validation but after downloading see that it's not there in css.

Answer (score 0):

All the Reveal classes are there but not Abide:

```
body.is-reveal-open {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Everything is in the .css file and there's a minified version if you want to use that instead.

If you want Reveal and Abide, you can export your own custom build. That's what I recommend you do.